# MySQL: creating new columns based on contents of other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I want to classify my customers based on which other tables they appear in. I doubt this syntax is remotely correct, but hopefully the gist comes through:

```
SELECT customer_id,
CASE customer_id
WHEN [customer_id is in tableA] THEN 'customer_segment_1'
WHEN [customer_id is in tableB] THEN 'customer_segment_2'
ELSE 'customer_segment_3' END
AS 'customer_segment'
FROM customers
```

Comment: yes. it's totally incorrect. you'd need to `join` your tableA an tableB, and then the values will be available for use in the `case` statement.

Comment: Can you please share your tables' struture and some sample data?

Comment: What was the reason for a downvote on this question? Seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if "`customer_id` is in `tableA`" you simply need to join that table, using `left outer` to account for IDs that are *not* in `tableA`:

```
SELECT tableC.customer_id,
       CASE  
          WHEN tableA.customer_id is not null THEN 'customer_segment_1'
          WHEN tableB.customer_id is not null THEN 'customer_segment_2'
    ELSE 'customer_segment_3' END
    AS customer_segment
 FROM tableC
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA on tableC.customer_id = tableA.customer_id     
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB on tableC.customer_id = tableB.customer_id
```

Comment: i knew i was missing some thing fundamental like that.  much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
SELECT tableC.customer_id,
CASE WHEN tableA.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'SegmentA' 
   WHEN tableB.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'SegmentB' ELSE 'SegmentC' END CASE AS Segment
FROM tableC LEFT JOIN tableA ON tableC.customer_id=tableA.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableC.customer_id=tableB.customer_id
```